# JS - Meteor returning multiple methods

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to find a way to return this:

```
 list: function() {
      return binary.find(), o8.find(), dec.find(), h16.find();
     },
```

as part of this template

```
<template name="convert">
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <button id="buttonchange" class="btn btn-info 
    {{buttonchangeclass}}">Convert Decimal</button>
    {{#each list}}
    <div class="row, rowbox">
      <h5 class="base">Number: <span class="bd">{{decimal}}</span></h5>
      <h5 class="base">Binary: <span class="bd">{{base2}}</span></h5>
      <h5 class="base">Octal: <span class="bd">{{octal}}</span></h5>
      <h5 class="base">Hex: <span class="bd">{{hex}}</span></h5>
      <button id="buttonrem2" class="btn btn-warning {{buttonrem2class}}">Clear</button>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

I am very new to both systems. So any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

As *clippy* might have said *It looks like you're trying to build a character table!*

Let's do this two different ways so that we can illustrate different aspects of Meteor, javascript, and spacebars templates.

**Array of objects**

```
Template.convert.helpers({
  list: function(){
    return [
      { base2: '0000', octal: '00' , decimal: 0 , hex: '00'},
      { base2: '0001', octal: '01' , decimal: 1 , hex: '01'},
      { base2: '1000', octal: '10' , decimal: 8 , hex: '08'},
      { base2: '1111', octal: '17' , decimal: 15 , hex: '0F'}
    ];
  })
});
```

In this case each *row* has an object that contains all the elements you wish to display in your template. While here the *list* helper defines all the data, in normal use you'd have a *collection* of data that's persisted in MongoDB and you use *Collection.find()* to return a *cursor*.

**Helper functions for formatting**

Since you're just doing format conversions it seems like overkill to store every format of every number. Let's use helpers to convert the numbers from decimal to other bases:

```
Template.convert.helpers({
  list: function(){
    return [0,1,8,15]; // same data as last time, but decimal only
  },
  base2: function(){
    return this.toString(2);
  },
  octal: function(){
    return this.toString(8);
  },
  hex: function(){
    return this.toString(16);
  }
});
```

Now you can easily handle any number that might come back from your *list* helper.

That's still a bit verbose though. And what if you want to display numbers in crazy bases like base 7 or 12? You can write a helper function that takes the base as a parameter:

```
Template.convert.helpers({
  rebase: function(base){
    return this.toString(base);
  })
});
```

And then use it in your template with `{{rebase 8}}` for octal etc...